How can I auto fix missing override after turning on `noImplicitOverride` in tsconfig
We enabled in our project tsconfig.json the noImplicitOverride rule, and now there are a lot of errors, is there a way to auto fix those by just adding override?

You can run this script (don't forget to save as .mjs):
import ts from 'typescript';
import path from 'node:path';
import fs from 'node:fs/promises';

const tsconfigPath = './tsconfig.json';

const cwd = process.cwd();

async function fixOverride() {
    const configFile = path.isAbsolute(tsconfigPath)
        ? tsconfigPath
        : ts.findConfigFile(cwd, ts.sys.fileExists, tsconfigPath);

    if (!configFile) {
        console.error('No tsconfig file found for path:', tsconfigPath);
        process.exit(1);
    }

    const config = ts.readConfigFile(configFile, ts.sys.readFile);

    const { options, fileNames } = ts.parseJsonConfigFileContent(
        config.config,
        ts.sys,

        // Resolve to the folder where the tsconfig file located
        path.dirname(tsconfigPath)
    );


    const program = ts.createProgram({
        rootNames: fileNames,
        options
    });


    if (fileNames.length === 0) {
        console.error('No files in the project.', {
            fileNames,
            options
        });

        process.exit(1);
    }
    let emitResult = program.emit();

    const overrideErrors = ts
        .getPreEmitDiagnostics(program)
        .concat(emitResult.diagnostics)
        .filter(diagnostic => [
            // This member must have an 'override' modifier because it overrides a member in the base class '{0}'.
            4114,
            // This parameter property must have an 'override' modifier because it overrides a member in base class '{0}'
            4115,
            // This member must have an 'override' modifier because it overrides an abstract method that is declared in the base class '{0}'.
            4116
        ].includes(diagnostic.code));

    const sortedErrors = sortErrors(overrideErrors);

    for (const diagnostic of sortedErrors) {
        await addOverride(diagnostic);
    }
}

/**
 *
 * @param {ts.Diagnostic} diagnostic
 * @returns {Promise<void>}
 */
async function addOverride(diagnostic) {
    const fileContent = (await fs.readFile(diagnostic.file.fileName, 'utf-8')).toString();
    let startIndex = diagnostic.start;

    if (fileContent.slice(0, startIndex).endsWith(' get ')) {
        startIndex -= 'get '.length;
    }
    if (fileContent.slice(0, startIndex).endsWith(' async ')) {
        startIndex -= 'async '.length;
    }
    if (fileContent.slice(0, startIndex).endsWith(' readonly ')) {
        startIndex -= 'readonly '.length;
    }

    const newFileContent = [fileContent.slice(0, startIndex), 'override ', fileContent.slice(startIndex)].join('');
    await fs.writeFile(diagnostic.file.fileName, newFileContent);
}

/**
 *
 * @param {ts.Diagnostic[]} errors
 * @returns {ts.Diagnostic[]}
 */
function sortErrors(errors) {
    // Sort by file path and start position from end to start
    // so we can insert override keyword without changing the start position of other errors in the same file that happen before
    return errors.slice(0).sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.file && b.file) {
            if (a.file.fileName === b.file.fileName) {
                return b.start - a.start;
            }

            return a.file.fileName.localeCompare(b.file.fileName);
        }

        return 0;
    });
}

fixOverride();

